# Create json fro Cassandra in go

Tags: go, cassandra

I have a table in Cassandra defined as the following :

```
CREATE TABLE book.book 
(
    title text PRIMARY KEY,
    amount decimal,
    available int,
    createdon timestamp
)
```

I am trying to select * from that table and return the values in json format. I am able to achieve that using

```
type Book struct {
       Title       string       `json:"title"`
       Amount      inf.Dec      `json:"amount"`
       CreatedOn   time.Time    `json:"createdon"`
       Available   int          `json:"available"`
    }
```

with

```
 func cassandraDisplay(query string, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster("xxxxxxxx:xxxx")
    session, _ := cluster.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()
    iter := session.Query("SELECT * FROM book.book").Iter()
    var book Book
    for iter.Scan(&book.Title ,&book.Amount ,&book.CreatedOn,&book.Available{
           fmt.Println(book.Title , book.Amount,book.CreatedO,book.Available)
           j, ERR:= json.Marshal(&iter)
           if ERR != nil {panic(ERR)}
           //do things with j 
    }
   if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {log.Fatal(err)}
}
```

but the requirement require a dynamic and no hard coding any info; since it is http service and the query will be passed through the url.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: maybe something like this: https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael,

You may want to use MapScan: https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#Iter.MapScan
This is as abstract as it can get.
From https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/master/cassandra_test.go:

```
...
testMap := make(map[string]interface{})
if !session.Query(`SELECT * FROM slice_map_table`).Iter().MapScan(testMap) {
        t.Fatal("MapScan failed to work with one row")
}
...
```

And after that you'll need to reflect/explore map content, but that's a different topic.